# Deleting elements in vector takes forever to complete

Tags: c++, memory, vector, memory-leaks

I have a vector of pointers that I really need to make sure the used memory is free before proceeding with other tasks in the program. I do not want to rely on operating system to manage the calls to `delete` so I want to do on my own because later I want to move this code to an embedded platform with limited memory. I have wrote the code below to test a simple scenario: **I have choosed the int pointer just for example...the actual data might be something else! e.g. a POD or class**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

#define NUM_ELEMENTS    1000000

double PCFreq = 0.0;
__int64 CounterStart = 0;

void StartCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    if (!QueryPerformanceFrequency(&li))
        std::cout << "QueryPerformanceFrequency failed!\r\n";

    PCFreq = double(li.QuadPart) / 1000.0;

    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    CounterStart = li.QuadPart;
}
double GetCounter()
{
    LARGE_INTEGER li;
    QueryPerformanceCounter(&li);
    return double(li.QuadPart - CounterStart) / PCFreq;
}

int main()
{
    /***** CREATE VECTOR **********/
    std::cout << "Generating " << NUM_ELEMENTS 
    << " elements." << std::endl;

    StartCounter();
    std::vector<int *>* vec = new std::vector<int*>;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_ELEMENTS; i++)
    {
        vec->push_back(new int(i));
    }

    std::cout <<  vec->size() << " Have been generated in " 
    << GetCounter() << "ms" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Destroying the vector..." << std::endl;

    /***** DELETE VECTOR **********/        

    StartCounter();

    while (!vec->empty())
    {
        delete vec->back(), vec->pop_back();
    }

    vec->clear();
    delete vec;

    std::cout << "It took " << GetCounter() << "ms to empty the vector!\r\n" 
    << "Press ENTER to exit." << std::endl; 

    //wait for key to exit
    std::cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

And here is the output to console:

```
Generating 1000000 elements.
1000000 Have been generated in 1077.96ms
Destroying the vector...
It took 16834.9ms to empty the vector!
Press ENTER to exit.
```

As you can see it takes about 1s to populate the vector but it takes almost 17s to get rid of it.

The code works, for 1000000 elements I get about 35MB of memory and then it starts to shrink back to about 1 MB just before the wait key part. But why it is so slow? how can I improve this behavior?

**Hmmm....no one cared to read my question carefully....anyways it was the visual studio playing dumb...I ran the program standalone and it took less than 100ms to fill and delete the vector! hope this experience is useful to others as well**

Comment: Why the strange way of deleting elements from the vector with `pop_back()`? You don't really need to do that.

Comment: If I do not do that there will be no visible memory shrinkage

Comment: No, `for (auto p : vec) delete p; vec.clear();`

Comment: @SaeidYazdani Not true. `pop_back` only destroys your last element, but it can't invalidate references and iterators. And the destructor for `int*` is trivial.

Comment: What about `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>>`? I mean, this isn't the 90's anymore. And seriously, a pointer to a vector? Why!?

Comment: If you really need to store pointers in the vector then avoid raw pointers and instead use smart pointers - i.e. use a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<type>>`.

Comment: int* was just a sample...the actual data might be some other types e.g. complex POD or classes

Comment: You are using a lot of pointers, is that really necessary? There is almost never a need to create a vector dynamically.

Comment: Well, to answer your question: Heap allocations and deallocations are expensive in C and C++. If you need a fast heap, either write your own custom allocator, or use .NET's managed heap.

Comment: And why do you need to store pointers inside the vector? Using values would be faster and more space efficient if you can get away with doing that.

Comment: "I do not want to rely on operating system to manage the calls to `delete`..." OS never cares about your program. And, your C++ runtime never calls for `delete`. Finalization of the resources should always be done by the program (your code). It can be done as you do manually, or it can be semi-automatic like `std::unique_ptr` or `boost::scoped_ptr`.

Comment: Also, you may want to check this out: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2014/12/10/hidden-costs-of-memory-allocation/

Comment: "no one cared to read my question carefully" - Where exactly in your question did you ever mention you were running this from any Visual Studio IDE ? Regardless, a platform independent version of your program using the standard library only [can be seen here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/73215528eedc2b38), and includes a *real* reason to dyna-allocate objects, namely polymorphic inheritance. It should compile on VS2015sp1 or later, and similar numbers should be obtainable when run in release-mode. Best of luck.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks for the code snippet

Comment: *"it was the visual studio playing dumb"* - More like safe. Sounds a lot like you were running a Debug build, and/or had enabled the [debug heap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/974tc9t1.aspx). This is a good thing, too, if you continue to write code like that in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The improvement is trivial: use `vector<int>` instead of `vector<int*>`, since you're storing only one element per pointer.

If your data is larger and you really need to store pointers, use `unique_ptr` or `boost::ptr_vector`. This isn't 1980 anymore, you can use RAII.

As for slow cleanup, it's probably because your runtime has a lot of entries in their small allocation structures and has to walk them all to find the correct one.

If you need to have a vector of pointers but need faster deallocation, try keeping the vector of pointers as it is and keep the actual data in `deque`-like container (a `list` of `array<data_t,32>`, perhaps? You'd have to do the index-keeping yourself, but it'd speed up deletion *if that's the bottleneck*).

Comment: Thanks. The int* is just for example, the actual data might be pointer of  some complex type

Comment: @SaeidYazdani That is not a good reason to use individually dynamically allocated objects.

Comment: @SaeidYazdani a more concrete reason would be a vector of polymorphic interface base pointers, and even then, they should be smart pointers.

Comment: @SaeidYazdani Vectors store all their data on the heap, so you don't need to dynamically allocate the elements yourself if that's the reason.

Comment: He says that he might want to move the code to an embedded platform. Maybe he'll have trouble finding enough contiguous memory.

Comment: I just found out that its the visual studio slowing it down. I ran the program standalone and it took less than 100ms to fill and delete the vector!